# Hadoop Single Node Silent Freeze

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce tool that freezes on the first mapper with no discernible output.  Because this is a single node installation, I have not been able to access the job tracker web interface to debug.  I get this behavior no matter what size the input file is.  I've been hacking on this for a full day and am ready to pull my hair out.  The output looks like this:

```
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
13/09/12 15:12:14 WA
RN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local1132137425_0001
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1132137425_0001_m_000000_0
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@339c98d3
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/axelmagn/EclipseWorkspace/AxelMagnusonCoursework/assign-2/data/in/input.csv:0+33554432
13/09/12 15:12:14 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/09/12 15:12:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/09/12 15:12:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/09/12 15:12:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/09/12 15:12:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/09/12 15:12:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/09/12 15:12:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 20% reduce 0%
```

and then it just hangs indefinitely.

The Tool routine (abridged):

```
        tempPath = new Path("/tmp/" + outDirPath.getName() + "_1_" + now);
        tempPath2 = new Path("/tmp/" + outDirPath.getName() + "_2_" + now);
        job1 = new VisitorCountJob(inFilePath, tempPath);
        success = job1.waitForCompletion(true);
        if (!success)
            throw new Exception("Visitor Count Job Failed.");
        job2 = new TopVisitorJob(tempPath, outDirPath, TOPN);
        success = job2.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1;
```

The Job:

```
public class VisitorCountJob extends Job {

    public static final String TAB = "\t";

    public VisitorCountJob(Path inputPath, Path outputPath)
            throws IOException {
        super();
        this.setJarByClass(VisitorCountJob.class);
        this.setJobName("Visitor Count");

        this.setInputFormatClass(VisitInputFormat.class);

        VisitInputFormat.setInputPaths(this, inputPath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(this, outputPath);

        this.setMapperClass(VisitorCountMapper.class);
        this.setReducerClass(VisitorCountReducer.class);

        this.setOutputKeyClass(Person.class);
        this.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        this.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
    }

}
```

The Mapper:

```
public class VisitorCountMapper extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Visit, Person, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Visit value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        try {
            Person visitor = value.getVisitor();
            context.write(visitor, new IntWritable(1));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

The reducer:

```
public class VisitorCountReducer extends
        Reducer<Person, IntWritable, Person, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Person visitor, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int count = 0;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            count += value.get();
        }
        context.write(visitor, new IntWritable(count));
    }

}
```

I've also written an InputFormat and RecordReader to generate Visit objects from raw text, but I'll leave them out for brevity unless anyone thinks they're relevant.

I'm really at my wit's end, so any help is very appreciated.

**edit:**  due to expressed interest, here are some of my data type implementations:

Person:

```
public class Person implements WritableComparable<Person>  {

    public Text firstName;
    public Text lastName;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(Text firstName, Text lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this(new Text(firstName), new Text(lastName));
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        firstName.readFields(in);
        lastName.readFields(in);

    }

    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        firstName.write(out);
        lastName.write(out);
    }

    public int compareTo(Person other) {

        int out;

        // give sorting preference to first name
        out = firstName.compareTo(other.firstName);
        if(out != 0)
            return out;
        return lastName.compareTo(other.lastName);
    }

}
```

VisitInputFormat:

```
public class VisitInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Visit> {

    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Visit> createRecordReader(
            InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) 
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        VisitRecordReader reader = new VisitRecordReader();
        reader.initialize(split, context);
        return reader;
    }
}
```

VisitRecordReader:

```
public class VisitRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Visit> {
    private LineRecordReader lineReader;
    private LongWritable lineKey;
    private Text lineValue;

    public VisitRecordReader() {
        lineReader = new LineRecordReader();
    }

    public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException {
        lineReader.initialize(genericSplit, context);
    }

    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
        return lineReader.nextKeyValue();
    }

    public LongWritable getCurrentKey() {
        return lineReader.getCurrentKey();
    }

    public Visit getCurrentValue() {
        String raw = lineReader.getCurrentValue().toString();
        return new Visit(raw);
    }

    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
        return lineReader.getProgress();
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        lineReader.close();
    }

}
```

Visit:

```
public class VisitRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Visit> {
    private LineRecordReader lineReader;
    private LongWritable lineKey;
    private Text lineValue;

    public VisitRecordReader() {
        lineReader = new LineRecordReader();
    }

    public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException {
        lineReader.initialize(genericSplit, context);
    }

    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
        return lineReader.nextKeyValue();
    }

    public LongWritable getCurrentKey() {
        return lineReader.getCurrentKey();
    }

    public Visit getCurrentValue() {
        String raw = lineReader.getCurrentValue().toString();
        return new Visit(raw);
    }

    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
        return lineReader.getProgress();
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        lineReader.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: How is person implemented? And your input format and record reader should be interesting as well.

Comment: I updated the post with this info

Comment: Why exactly do you need your own input format for that? Just use the simple `TextInputFormat` and create your `Visit`s in the map method. Yet still, this shouldn't be a problem in your case. Can you run a profiler/debugger to see where it hangs? Usually this is a GC problem, so you should see a lot of CPU usage or GC activity.

Comment: Mostly because I'm new to the toolset and wanted to try my hand at writing my own InputFormat.

Comment: I haven't quite mastered the fine art of hadoop profiling, but a quick check on top shows both CPU and Mem at under 15% capacity.  The problem also persists if I instantiate the visits in the mapper and do away with the InputFormat.

Comment: Then I would say that it looks like a locking problem, what version are you using?

Comment: hadoop v1.2.1, jre-1.7.0. I've noticed that very similar mappers using different data types don't seem to have the same problem

Comment: JRE 1.7.0 may compile loops into wrong code, maybe you should upgrade. Latest should be 1.7.40 now.